# Momentjs duration is completely incorrect

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm running this exact code, and `momentjs` is getting the number of hours entirely incorrect:

```
   const minutes = 2100
   const duration = moment.duration(minutes, 'minutes')
   const inHours = duration.hours()

   console.log(inHours)
```

The answer is clearly **35**, but it's just saying **11**.

There's not really much more context I can provide here, as it's really something very basic.

Can anyone see where this'd be going wrong?

Comment: What is moment?

Comment: I just tried it and my result is `11`.
if you rewrite this code in a new file, what's your result ?

Comment: How is your answer is clearly 35 ?

Comment: 2100 minutes = 35 hrs (2100/60 = 35)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Moment Duration will convert it into `days, hours, minutes, seconds`

> 2100 minutes = 35 hrs = 24 + 11 hrs = 1 day + 11 hours

If you type `duration.days()`, it will give you 1.

If you want the duration as hours, you can do : `duration.asHours()`

A far more performance optimized new generation code that is also thread safe for doing this would be: `var hours = 2100/60`

Answer (score 2):

You can directly get the hours by using `.asHours()`

```js
const minutes = 2100
const duration = moment.duration(minutes, 'minutes').asHours()
console.log(duration)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```